# Ortho Camera like Autocad with OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, camera, graphic

I'm going to write a program to view dwg file. I'm using SharpGL library.
I'm wrote a mouse control camera for 3D.
This is a code:

```
private void Device_OpenGLDraw(object sender, SharpGL.SceneGraph.OpenGLEventArgs args)
    {
        OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;

        gl.ClearColor((float)s3.Value, (float)s2.Value, (float)s1.Value, 0f);

        gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.LoadIdentity();

        gl.Ortho(-wheelx, wheelx, -wheely, wheely, 0.1f, 1000000000.0f);

        gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW);

        gl.Rotate(xrot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        gl.Rotate(yrot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        gl.Translate(-xpos, -ypos, -zpos);

        DrawScene();   
        gl.Flush();
    }

private void Device_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(Device);
        x = (int)Math.Ceiling(position.X);
        y = -(int)Math.Ceiling(position.Y);

        if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            diffx = x - lastx; //check the difference between the 
            diffy = y - lasty; //check the difference between the 


            xrot += (float)diffy * 0.05f * (float)Math.Min(wheelx, wheely); ; //set the xrot to xrot with the addition
            yrot += (float)diffx * 0.05f * (float)Math.Min(wheelx, wheely); ;    //set the xrot to yrot with the addition

            if (xrot < 0)
            {
                xrot = 360;
            }
            if (xrot > 360)
            {
                xrot = 0;
            }

            if (yrot < 0)
            {
                yrot = 360;
            }
            if (yrot > 360)
            {
                yrot = 0;
            }

        }

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            diffx = x - lastx; //check the difference between the 
            diffy = y - lasty; //check the difference between the 

            float xrotrad, yrotrad;
            yrotrad = (yrot / 180 * PI);
            xrotrad = (xrot / 180 * PI);

            float xs = (float)(Math.Tan(xrotrad));
            float xc = (float)(Math.Cos(xrotrad));
            float yc = (float)(Math.Cos(yrotrad));
            float ys = (float)(Math.Sin(yrotrad));

            ypos -= (xc * (float)diffy)* 0.003f * (float)Math.Min(wheelx, wheely);     
            zpos -= (-yc * (float)diffy + ys * (float)diffx) * 0.003f * (float)Math.Min(wheelx, wheely);
            xpos += (-ys * (float)diffy - yc * (float)diffx) * 0.003f * (float)Math.Min(wheelx, wheely);

            l5.Content = xc;
        }

        lastx = x; //set lastx to the current x position
        lasty = y; //set lasty to the current y position
    }
```

For 2D camera works a good. On 3D a have problem:

When X angle is between 0-180 degree, vertical moving works a good, but X angle is between 180-360 (ABOUT 315 degree) , vertical moving not working properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to call gl.LoadIdentity(); after gl.MatrixMode(OpenGL.GL_MODELVIEW)?

Comment: This solution not working

Comment: I think you need to hold rotation as matrix, because with current code it is hard to get correct rotation. It happened because when you rotated around xrot, Y axe was changed (it is not [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]). It is gimbal lock problem, if I remember correct. You can look this topic https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/171651-Rotation-Matrix

Comment: I need this solution [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWlEIxpIgWw)

Comment: I am not sure, what it is what you need. But did you see this lesson http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/arcball_rotation/19003/?